# Vue-Form-Generator schema is not reactive to computed properties

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have computed property in my data `this.coinPairingOptions` that needs to render its radio buttons based on some of the other fields in this `schema`. I have reduced the amount of code in the file to save space.

```
data: function () {
  return {
    schema: {
     {model: "symbolPair", type: "radios", label: "Pair with", values: 
      this.coinPairingOptions, required: true}
},
computed: {
    coinPairingOptions() {
    console.log("computing coinPairingOptions")
    let coin = this.model.symbol.toUpperCase();
    let options = [];

    if (this.model.exchange === 'Coinbase') {
      options = this.getCoinbasePairs
    } else if (this.model.exchange === 'Binance') {
      options = this.getBinancePairs
    } else {
    }
    console.log(options.get(coin));
    return options.get(coin);
  },
}
```

In the dev tools I can see the computed property changing to the correct values however it is not changing in the data. Apparently, this is appropriate behavior, but what is a way around this? I have tried putting `{{this.coinPairingOptions}}` in the html and it errors because it's a computed property with not value initially.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `computed property` in `data`, because `data` evaluates before the `computed properties` did.

You can use a `watcher` to achieve the intended result. Have a look at the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch), you can add the argument `immediate` to trigger the callback immediately with the current value of the expression.

`Computed properties` are already accessible in the `template` by using `{{}}`. You don't need to put a `this` in front of the computed.

Comment: So this function relies on several properties, do I just watch one of them and it will watch all of them?

Comment: And this several properties are all part of the schema object?

Comment: Yes, they are. Its a really big form.

Comment: So in this case you can set a `watcher` on the schema object and when all fields are filled in, you can do the same as in your `computed property`. You reduced your code, so I don't know what your data structure exactly look like (`this.model.symbol` doesn't match with `schema: {model: "symbolPair",...`) but when all information are in one object, you can simply set a 'watcher' on it like this: `watch: { schema: { immediate: true, handler(val) { // your conditions }}}`. Hopefully this helps, I'm sorry if I misunderstood something.

Comment: I tried doing 2 watchers and putting the data in a method and when any of those 2 methods change I do get some data changing. BUT it is not changing in the Vue-Form-Generator schema.